# Chips vs Fries: was this a tongue-in-cheek joke in "A Fish Called Wanda"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, connotations

Here's a familiar sight:

[image]

We call them French fries, or just fries, in the States, as well as in Canada. They're often referred to as *chips* over in England. In France they are, of course, good old *frites* (as well as in some parts of Scandinavia).

Now here's what proper *chips* should look like, if you ask me:

[image]

*That* is what comes to *my* mind *first* when you mention "chips" to me in a discussion involving food: thin slices of potato, fried, and consumed cold as a snack.

Etymology aside, here's what an *American* actor playing an *American* character (a comically vulgar dimwit, and emphatically disdainful of all things English throughout the movie) has to say in ***A Fish Called Wanda***:

> OTTO. No hassle. There's plenty of time. I'll just sit here and **eat my chips** till you tell me. **The English contribution to** world cuisine: **the chip**.

Why would *this* character (of all people) call fries *chips*, and why would he imply (or does he?) that they're a *British* invention? What's the joke? What am I missing? What or whom are we making fun of in this case?

P.S. The movie was written and directed by the *Monty Python* team, so the joke must be British in spirit.

Comment: You sound like a native speaker... did you mean to post this on [english.se]? This question has nothing to do with learning the English Language.... I mean, arguably, you could even post it on [movies.se].

Comment: @Catija: I have been exiled for a month on ELU for not being nice. That said, this question is an _excellent_ opportunity for people who are desperately trying to learn. It has _everything_ to do with the language.  I'm not breaking any rules; what's wrong with a bit of entertainment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with learning the English language. It is clearly asking for in-depth context that is appropriate on ELU, not ELL.

Comment: For the record Ricky, potato crisps in England are potato chips in the USA.  French fries in the US are roughly similar to chips in England, although they are about as similar to what we call "potato wedges" here.  This is the nugget of learning in your post.  The rest is part entertainment and part, well, grandstanding.

Answer (score 4):

In England, **chips** as you think of them (potato chips) are called **crisps**, since they are ***crispy*** and **fries** in the elongated potato sense are called **chips**. British **chips** are usually more equivalent to American steak fries (think: biggish, bulky, smaller cousin to North American potato wedges).

I believe the full quote goes something like:

> Otto: No hassle. There's plenty of time. I'll just sit here and eat my chips till you tell me. The English contribution to world cuisine: the chip. What do the English usually eat with **chips** to make them more interesting? Wait a moment! It's **fish**. Isn't it?

OTTO (Kevin Kline) calls them **chips** because he is talking to someone English, KEN (Michael Palin), and the claim that the English invented it is called **irony**, something which the English are very good at (or you may think of it as sarcasm). In the previous line he makes a point by saying:

> What do the English usually eat with **chips** to make them more interesting?

obviously conceding that fries/chips are boring in and of themselves, and potatoes are humble in nature, and being the **English contribution**, well, couldn't they have done better, after all they did have an Empire, and most of the world speaks their language: **English**, and...

Actually, **fish and chips**, with malted vinegar or brown sauce (depending where one is from) wrapped in newspaper (back in the day, people would claim they could tell if an FT or Times was used) and possibly a side of mushy peas, is one of the many **English contributions to world cuisine**

Comment: Monty Python was very good at delivering exactly what you're talking about. Much more popular in the State than in the UK and rightfully so. "Chips or death?", not quite the same ring as "Cake or death?"

Comment: I actually remember those days as a visitor to England, when I could occasionally see newspaper ink on the side of my fish.  :)

Comment: @Stephie: Nothing better to do?

Comment: @Ricky I can think of many things I would prefer to do. But as this is a comunity that works only if everyone chips in...

Comment: @Stephie shows another use of the word "chips", very good :)

Comment: @Ricky He says "chips" because he is already planning to say "fish" later on and there is a meal called "fish & chips" or "fish 'n' chips", 'n' is a contraction of "and". Nobody calls it "fish and fries", although that would work alliteratively.